# BillSAFE does not secure this transaction , my order is decline

Tags: payment-gateway, prestashop, billing

i have one e-commerce site made in prestashop and i used the BillSafe  as my payment gateway but every time my order is decline when debug the code it give me following response from BIllSafe

```
[ANSWER] => Array
    (
        [ack] => OK
        [custom_0] => FOOO
        [custom_1] => FAAA
        [custom_2] => Muhahah
        [status] => DECLINED
        [declineReason_code] => 101
        [declineReason_message] => BillSAFE does not secure this transaction
    )
```

Comment: do you have SSL installed on your server?

Comment: Have you tried asking BillSAFE themselves? There's nothing in the documentation?

Comment: [The manual](http://www.billsafe.de/integration/manuals/BillSAFE_API.pdf) says that 101 is actually "authentication failure". Do you definitely have the correct credentials? Now I definitely think you need to talk to their support.

Comment: @Rup yes my credential is correct

Comment: @nDudani yes i have installed SSL on my server , but i tried it without SSL it still same response from BillSafe

Comment: OK. Just to be clear, is `FOOO FAAA Muhahah` actually what you're seeing in the response or is that you anonymising your own request?

Comment: @Rup what i get the response from BillSafe is in above code , if i remove break point it will redirect to my payment page

Comment: Well `FOOO FAAA Muhahah` looks like test output to me - I can't see why you'd use those as real diagnostic errors. You're not actually connecting to their development environment, are you? And really please email the BillSafe support if you haven't already. They will be able to look at the code to see where this is coming from, and to look at the server logs to see exactly what happened to your request on the server. They have more information than we do and they have the expertise. There's really no reason not to talk to them directly.

Comment: @Rup ,Thanks for give me the right direction, well message like **FOOO FAAA Muhahah** is default in BillSafe module of Prestashop , i search how to connect to development environment but i didn't get any thing :(

Answer (score 1):

Your declineReason_code is 101 that means `Auth failure`

Kindly check you log in credential and API URL.

List of error code and reason.

```
100 No auth parameter is set
101 Auth failure
102 Not all auth parameters set
103 Invalid merchantId
104 Invalid merchantLicence
105 Invalid applicationSignature
106 Invalid applicationVersion
107 Merchant not found
108 Request to productive system not allowed yet
198 Error during application log 
199 Unknown error during authentication
2xx Mit „2“ beginnende Fehler-Codes behandeln Validierungs-Fehler
200 No transaction identifier set
201 Parameter transactionId is invalid
202 Transaction not found
203 Transaction does not belong to merchant
204 OrderNumber matched more than 1 order
215 Ein erforderlicher Parameter wurde nicht angegeben
216 Ein Parameter enthält einen ungültigen Wert
220 Encoding other than UTF8 detected
3xx Mit „3“ beginnende Fehler-Codes behandeln Ausführungs-Fehler
301 An execution error occurred
302 Transaction has a wrong status for this method
303 Customer has not yet completed the transaction
304 Frist für den Aufruf der Operation ist abgelaufen
305 No data to return
306 Transaction already has customer payments
399 Internal error in method
8xx Mit „8“ beginnende Fehler-Codes behandeln API spezifische Fehler
801 No Service found
802 No method set
803 Invalid method set
804 Invalid request
999 Unbekannter Fehler
```

**Sandbox**

Payment Gateway : https://sandbox-payment.billsafe.de/V200

NVP API-Server  : https://sandbox-nvp.billsafe.de/V208

**Live**

Payment Gateway : https://payment.billsafe.de/V200

NVP API-Server  : https://nvp.billsafe.de/V208

Comment: thnks regading "101" error code and i had checked my credential it correct and i have used the Right url for live and demo URL , is may be issue from BillSafe side i have contact support team but didn't get any response :(

Answer (score 1):

In your output there are some test data to be seen. Try using some real data => Not "FAAA Muhahah" or "Paul Positiv", which is found in some BillSAFE guidelines. The test data does not pass the BillSAFE validation, even though your merchant account has been activated.

I advise you to enable logging. Log file will give you more insight on what is going on.